# Java inherited method using the wrong class

Tags: java, inheritance

So I have a parent class, here refered to as A, and class B which extends A.

```
public class A
{
  private int a = 1;
  public int getA()
  {
    return a;
  }
}

public class B extends A
{
  private int a = 2;
}
```

However, when B.getA() is called, it returns 1 from class A instead of the 2 in class B. Did I do something wrong? Because I had a similar problem a couple of months ago, and it miraculously worked after a lot of messing around. The only difference is that the method deals with adding an object to an ArrayList.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Private variables are private even to subclasses.  A.a and B.a are two completely different fields.  If you want to change data in a subclass, make it a protected field or (better yet) add an optionally abstract getter to the parent class and override it in the subclass.

Comment: So, the inherited method is calling A.a? So I should override the inherited method to call B.a, right?

Comment: Yes.  That is right.  (But you wouldn't "call" `B.a` ... you would use it.  You only "call" methods.)

Comment: I am talking about the getters.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the fields defined in a class are *never* overriden in subclasses, *irrespective* of the fields' access modifiers.

If you declare a field in a subclass with the same name as a field in the superclass, your subclass actually has two fields with that name.  The field inheritted from the superclass is *hidden* in the subclass, but (if the access rules permit it) the superclass version can be accessed in the subclass; e.g. by qualifying the field name with the class name.

(In your particular example, the access rules *forbid* `B` to access the `a` declared in `A`. A  `private` field or method can only be accessed from the class itself or nested classes.  But even so, there *are* two fields called `a` in any `B` instance instance.)